# CAML query issue with or(and(and + or))

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I got a correlation id problem from SPQuery with the follwing query:
any help please

```
  sb.Append("<Where><Or>");//
                    sb.Append("<And>");
                        sb.Append("<Or>");

                            foreach (SPUser userr in usersOfGroup)
                            {
                                sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value   
  Type='User'>sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='User'>" + userr.LoginName.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1] + "</Value></Eq>")+ "</Value></Eq>");


                            }

                        sb.Append("</Or>");

                        sb.Append("<And>");
                            sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value 
   Type='Text'>" + ConstVariables.DossiersEnvoyés + "</Value></Eq>");
                            sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value 
   Type='Text'>" + ConstVariables.DossiersASuivre + "</Value></Eq>");
                        sb.Append("</And>");
                    sb.Append("</And>");
                    sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef 
   Name='Envoy_x00e9__x0020_vers_x0020_directeur' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
   </Eq>");

                    sb.Append("</Or></Where>");//
                    sb.Append("<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='True' />
   </OrderBy>");
```

Comment: What is does the generated CAML look like? I suspect it's because of how you are foreaching over the usersOfGroups in that it is generating too many nodes.

Comment: only two users there

Comment: Isn't this CAML query not valid without having the outermost `<Query> </Query>` tags? Also, you seem to have a syntax error on line 7/8. I'm guessing it should just be `sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='User'>" + userr.LoginName.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]  + "</Value></Eq>");`

Comment: no there's no error in my code there this is the real code:  sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value   
  Type='User'>sb.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='User'>" + userr.LoginName.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1] + "</Value></Eq>")+ "</Value></Eq>");

Comment: it does work without <Query> </Query> because it's an SPQuery

Comment: What did the ULS logs say the error is when you look for that correlationid?

Comment: In what language is that line valid markup?? (no actual answer needed; I can't help with that). Regardless, you could test your query logic by using tools like [CAML Query Helper](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/) or [CAMLBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16524936/2554793) in order to validate syntax and result values, or even to build the entire query string for you.